# How to adjust maxWidth on container based on custom breakpoints when using muiTheme with material-ui

Tags: reactjs, grid, material-ui

I'm trying to get my head around using the createMuiTheme and adjust the maxWidth for the different breakpoints I have created. For now I have made the following breakpoint values:

```
import { Container as Container_, Grid } from '@material-ui/core'
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles"


const breakPointValues = {
    xs: 0,
    sm: 768,
    md: 1025,
    lg: 1280,
    xl: 1360,
}
```

Then I create a theme with these breakpoints.

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    breakpoints: { values: breakPointValues },

    overrides: ({
        MuiContainer: ({
            root: {

            },
            maxWidthXl: //????
        })
    })
})
```

I need to adjust the maxWidth to something else than the standard that is giving. For example I need to set maxWidth for every viewport larger than 1279px --> so for large and xlarge.

It should be possible using the maxWidthXl, but can't find an example how to write the code, as the type is something else than a string.

I'm using typescript btw, and the error I'm getting looks like this.

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'CreateCSSProperties<{}> | ((props: {}) => CreateCSSProperties<{}>)'.
```

I have searched and found that I maybe should be using the createStyles from @material-ui/core/styles, but can't find any example in the documentation how this should be.

**Rest of code:**

```
    const Container = (props: Props) => {

    return (
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <ContainerStyled fluid={props.fluid} {...props.fluid ? { maxWidth: false } : { fixed: false }}>
                <Grid container spacing={6}>
                    {props.children}
                </Grid>
            </ContainerStyled>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
    )
}

export default Container
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Just dealt with this issue, myself. The following worked:

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles/';

export default createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
        MuiContainer: {
            maxWidthXs: {
                maxWidth: '300px !important'
            },
            maxWidthSm: {
                maxWidth: '600px !important'
            },
            maxWidthMd: {
                maxWidth: '900px !important'
            },
            maxWidthLg: {
                maxWidth: '1200px !important'
            },
            maxWidthXl: {
                maxWidth: '1500px !important'
            },
            maxWidthXxl: {
                maxWidth: '1920px !important'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Edit: This can also be done without overrides, using the following, but it will override default Theme values for all the components, not just the Container:

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles/';

export default createMuiTheme({
    breakpoints: {
        keys: {
            0: 'xs',
            1: 'sm',
            2: 'md',
            3: 'lg',
            4: 'xl',
            5: 'full'
        },
        values: {
            xs: 0,
            sm: 600,
            md: 900,
            lg: 1200,
            xl: 1500,
            full: window.innerWidth
        }
    }
});
```